# PhpStorm - in the editor, open file at cursor

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm editing the file ~/subdir/hello.html which contains the following line:

```
<script src="js/hogan.js"></script>
```

Is there a command in PHPStorm to quickly open ~/subdir/js/hogan.js when keyboard cursor is inside double quotes?

Comment: Your code has a lot of typos but if you correct it to `<script src="js/hogan.js"></script>` you can Ctrl+Click on the name.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, right. Both work, Ctrl+Click is "go to declaration". Fixed the code.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I found that "Navigate to implementation(s)" (Ctrl-Alt-B) does the trick in this case, as well as "Navigate to declaration" (Ctrl-Click or Ctrl-B)